# SHA2-256 of entire SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sha

Can I calculate hash for an entire database in SQL Server, in order to compare hash after duplicating it?

For example, I send the `.mdf` file to a my friend, he mounts the `.mdf` file on his SQL Server. I calculate the hash of the entire content and structure of my database and I send the hash to my friend. He make same calculation and compare hashes, now we are sure we have same data and structure in database.

Comment: I imagine that to be very tedious, but reading everything (in an appropriate representation) and hashing it is possible. So, yes you can.

Comment: Define `duplicate`? Backup database command or are you just copying data between existing databases/

Comment: Take a peek at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a4721ee-7188-48aa-afe2-2a854c3559d7/check-if-two-databases-are-identical-the-same-table-structure-functions-sps?forum=transactsql

Comment: I suspect that the only way an `mdf` file would be a true "duplicate" would be if the database file is detached and the copied, and hasn't been attached to a differentserver yet. I *suspect* a restored of a backup would not have the same hash.